# What is this algebra rule: dividing/subtracting leaves 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Lets say I am doing some algebra. I want to simplify and see if I can put some terms outside of a parenthesis. I forget what it is called when this is done but a 1 is left in place of the removed term.

What is it and how can one do it.

Here is an example.
$$
2(e^{-x^2}-2x^{2}e^{-x^2})
$$

$$
=
$$

$$
2e^{-x^2}(1+(-2x^2))
$$

I don't get it.

Comment: factoring out a term maybe ?

Comment: It sounds like you are describing the process :$(a\cdot x+x)=(a\cdot x+1\cdot x)=(a+1)\cdot x$.  The first equals sign follows from the properties of $1$, namely that it is the multiplicative identity.  The second equals sign follows from distributivity of multiplication over addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is called *factoring.* Recall also that $1 \cdot u = u$.